# ASP.NET Core - handling 404 and 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I try to handle 404 and 500 error in ASP.NET MVC 6.

1. I have Action in controller which render page with error status and description:

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("/Errors/{status}")]
   public IActionResult Errors(int status)
   {
       var model = Mapper.Map<ErrorViewModel>(BaseData);
       model.ErrorCode = status;

       if (error_descriptions.ContainsKey(status))
           model.Description = error_descriptions[status];
       else
           model.Description = "Неизвестная ошибка";

       return View(model);
   }
   ```
2. I enable status code pages and exception handler:

   app.UseExceptionHandler("/Errors/500");
   app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Errors/{0}");

I want to ger `404` error when url doesn't match any route and when queryes to Database return empty sequencies (access to nonexists elements).

I've got `InvalidOperationException` when LINQ return empty sequence (`the sequence contains no elements`). I want to handle global exception, show `404` in this case and `500` in other.

3. I make a simple filter and check Exception in `OnException`:

   ```
   public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
   {
       logger.LogError(context.Exception.Message);

       if (context.Exception is System.InvalidOperationException) ;
           //NEED TO CALL HomeController.Error(404) 
   }
   ```

**It works, but I don't know how to call my action and show error page**

Comment: You shouldn't rely on an exception to get you to your 404 page. Throwing exceptions is expensive. You are better off using something like `SingleOrDefault()` for example, then checking the return is `null`.

Comment: Thanks, now I think so

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model in the `OnException` method like

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
{
       var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, "YourError Controller","Errors");
}
```

Comment: `override` gets error but it works perfectly without it.